# Забыл рутовый пароль FreeBSD, что делать?

Tags: freebsd, пароль, root

Есть сервер с FreeBSD, внутри что-то полезное. Рутовый доступ утерян. Как попасть внутрь?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вообще говоря, предпочтительным способом рутового доступа к *BSD является не логин пользователем root, а sudo из-под непривилегированного пользователя. Но рассмотрим ситуацию, когда всё, что у вас есть - сервер с FreeBSD и никаких доступов к нему.

**Способ 1, простой**

Рутовый пароль можно принудительно сменить, для этого понадобится физический доступ к консоли сервера (то есть физическое подключение с клавиатурой, либо, если речь о colocation, доступ через IP-KVM или IPMI/BMC) и перезагрузка сервера. Для этого выполните следующие действия:

1. Перезагрузите сервер (если он включён; просто включите, если выключен)
2. При загрузке ОС выберите загрузку в однопользовательский режим (опция меню "Boot FreeBSD in single user mode", обычно идёт под пунктом 4)
3. Нажмите <kbd>Enter</kbd> в ответ на вопрос "Enter full pathname of shell or RETURN for /bin/sh:"
4. Теперь сервер загружен в "сингл". При этом монтируется только раздел `/`, причём в режиме "только чтение" (остальные не монтируются вообще). Перемонтируйте его в "нормальный" режим, позволяющий осуществлять операции записи: `mount -o rw /`
5. Теперь можно изменить рутовый пароль командой `passwd` - старый пароль при этом не спросят
6. Заменили пароль? Возобновите работу ОС в стандартном, многопользовательском режиме - для этого достаточно выйти из "синглового" шелла, набрав `exit`.

Данный способ (логин в сингл без рутового пароля) работает из коробки. Чтобы отключить эту возможность (чтобы кто-то, имеющий физический доступ к серверу, не сменил вам рутовый пароль), нужно изменить настройку физической консоли: в файле `/etc/ttys` изменить строчку

```
console        none                            unknown off secure
```

на

```
console        none                            unknown off insecure
```

Попробуйте теперь перезагрузиться в однопользовательский режим - без знанния текущего рутового пароля в него не попасть.

**Способ 2, посложнее**

Этот способ работает, даже если выполнены рекомендации по защите от загрузки в "сингл" без рутового пароля, так как он вообще не требует загрузки целевой ОС, чтобы изменить в ней рутовый пароль.

1. Загрузитесь на целевом сервере в FreeBSD с другого раздела или вообще с другого носителя - HDD, CD, с USB-флэшки, через сеть по PXE, через virtual media посредством BMC/KVM, etc.
2. Примонтируйте корневой раздел ОС, от которой забыт пароль, в текущую загруженную ОС:

   ```
   mkdir /mnt/rootpart && mount /dev/ad0s1 /mnt/rootpart
   ```

   (где `ad0s1`, соответственно, указывает на корневой раздел ОС, доступ к которой нужно восстановить - в конкретном случае буквы и цифры могут различаться)
3. Смените "текущий" корневой раздел на примонтированный:

   ```
   chroot /mnt/rootpart
   ```

   Теперь Вы работаете как будто в той, с утерянным паролем, ОС.
4. Теперь можно изменить рутовый пароль командой `passwd` - старый пароль при этом не спросят
5. Выходим из `chroot` "наружу" в запущенную ОС:

   ```
   exit
   ```
6. Отмонтируем препарируемый корневой раздел ОС, к которой меняем пароль:

   ```
   umount /mnt/rootpart
   ```
7. Готово. Можно перезагрузиться обратно в интересующую вас ОС и логиниться с новым рутовым паролем.